# How to declare a global variable set to a method in __init__ in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, class, oop, global-variables

I am new to object-oriented programming and I have some trouble with declaring global variables that are set to a method inside a class. I declared them in the `__init__` method (I want them to be inside the class, not outside) with `self.censored_transcript = self.apply_filter()`, and within this file, everything works fine. But when I import the class in a different .py file and instantiate the Profanity class, the following error occurs: `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'censored_transcript' referenced before assignment`. I have done quite some research on this topic but can't find anything that fits my case. The `global` statement does not work. Can anyone please let me know how I can fix this? Thank you very much in advance!

File 1 (file to be imported), called `profanity_filter.py`:

```
from better_profanity import profanity


class Profanity(object):

    def __init__(self, transcript_filename, wordlist_filename):
        self.__transcript_filename = transcript_filename
        self.__wordlist_filename = wordlist_filename

        self.__transcript = self.__load_transcript()
        self.censored_transcript = self.apply_filter()

    def __load_transcript(self):
        f = open(self.__transcript_filename, "r")
        file = f.read()
        f.close()

        return file

    def apply_filter(self):
        if __name__ == "__main__":
            profanity.load_censor_words_from_file(self.__wordlist_filename)
            censored_transcript = profanity.censor(self.__transcript)

        return censored_transcript
```

File 2 (test file):

```
from profanity_filter import Profanity


# Instantiate the Profanity class:
p = Profanity("sample_transcript.txt", "profanity_wordlist.txt")


# Apply the profanity filter.
censored_transcript = p.apply_filter()
print(censored_transcript)
```

Comment: For what purpose you used `if __name__ == "__main__"`? Maybe you are looking for `Singletone` architect pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `self.censored_transcript` in all places inside your class - `self` refers to current object of class. Each created object of your class will store self `self` set of variables available.

`censored_transcript` without `self` treated as regular local variable which will be newly created for each call of method.

**Error cause:**
When method `def apply_filter(self)` gets called from outer .py file, `if __name__ == "__main__"` check will be false and local variable `censored_transcript` will not be created inside this method. So, `return censored_transcript` tries to return local variable with unassigned value and fails.

**Solution 1:** in `apply_filter(self)` you can use object's `censored_transcript`, not local, to save result. Just append `self.` before it. And you do not need to return something from this method:

```py
from better_profanity import profanity


class Profanity(object):

    def __init__(self, transcript_filename, wordlist_filename):
        self.__transcript_filename = transcript_filename
        self.__wordlist_filename = wordlist_filename

        self.__transcript = self.__load_transcript()
        self.apply_filter()  # changed

    def __load_transcript(self):
        f = open(self.__transcript_filename, "r")
        file = f.read()
        f.close()

        return file

    # changed
    def apply_filter(self):
        profanity.load_censor_words_from_file(self.__wordlist_filename)
        self.censored_transcript = profanity.censor(self.__transcript)
```

**Solution 2:** use a local variable, but assign value to it without `if`. Or even omit this local variable:

```py
from better_profanity import profanity


class Profanity(object):

    def __init__(self, transcript_filename, wordlist_filename):
        self.__transcript_filename = transcript_filename
        self.__wordlist_filename = wordlist_filename

        self.__transcript = self.__load_transcript()
        self.censored_transcript = self.apply_filter()

    def __load_transcript(self):
        f = open(self.__transcript_filename, "r")
        file = f.read()
        f.close()

        return file

    # changed
    def apply_filter(self):
        profanity.load_censor_words_from_file(self.__wordlist_filename)
        return profanity.censor(self.__transcript)
```